# Problem skipping line whilst iterating using previous line and current line comparison

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have a list of sorted data arranged so that each item in the list is a csv line to be written to file.

The final step of the script checks the contents of each field and if all but the last field match then it will copy the current line's last field onto the previous line's last field.

I would like to as I've found and processed one of these matches skip the current line where the field was copied from thus only leaving one of the lines.

Here's an example set of data

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,something
field1,field2,field3,field4,else
```

Desired output

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,something else
```

This is what I have so far

```
output_csv = ['field1,field2,field3,field4,something',
              'field1,field2,field3,field4,else']

# run through the output
# open and create a csv file to save output
with open('output_table.csv', 'w') as f:

    previous_line = None
    part_duplicate_line = None
    part_duplicate_flag = False

    for line in output_csv:
        part_duplicate_flag = False

        if previous_line is not None:                    
            previous = previous_line.split(',')
            current = line.split(',')

            if (previous[0] == current[0] 
                and previous[1] == current[1]
                and previous[2] == current[2]
                and previous[3] == current[3]):
                print(previous[0], current[0])
                previous[4] = previous[4].replace('\n', '') + ' ' + current[4]
                part_duplicate_line = ','.join(previous)
                part_duplicate_flag = True
                f.write(part_duplicate_line)

            if part_duplicate_flag is False:
                f.write(previous_line)

        previous_line = line
```

ATM script adds the line but doesn't skip the next line, I've tried various renditions of continue statements after part_duplicate_line is written to file but to no avail.

Comment: Are you reading in the data from somewhere? From your code - it looks like you are trying to read lines from `output_csv` and write it to `output_table.csv`. If yes, what is output_csv? a `list`?

Comment: I've updated the code as to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want one entry for each combination of the first 4 *fields*

You can use a `dict` to aggregate data -

```
#First we extract the key and values
output_csv_keys = list(map(lambda x: ','.join(x.split(',')[:-1]), output_csv)) 
output_csv_values = list(map(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1], output_csv))

#Then we construct a dictionary with these keys and combine the values into a list
from collections import defaultdict
output_csv_dict = defaultdict(list) 
for key, value in zip(output_csv_keys, output_csv_values): 
  output_csv_dict[key].append(value) 

#Then we extract the key/value combinations from this dictionary into a list
for_printing = [','.join([k, ' '.join(v)]) for k, v in output_csv_dict.items()]
print(for_printing)
#Output is ['field1,field2,field3,field4,something else']
#Each entry of this list can be output to the csv file
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose to encapsulate what you want to do in a function where the important part obeys this logic:

***either*** join the `new` info to the `old` record
***or*** output the `old` record and forget it

of course at the end of the loop we have in any case a dangling `old` record to output

```
def join(inp_fname, out_fname):
    '''Input file contains sorted records, when two (or more) records differ
only in the last field, we join the last fields with a space
and output only once, otherwise output the record as-is.'''
    ######################### Prepare for action ##########################
    from csv import reader, writer
    with open(inp_fname) as finp, open(out_fname, 'w') as fout:
        r, w = reader(finp), writer(fout)
        ######################### Important Part starts here ############## 
        old = next(r)
        for new in r:
            if old[:-1] == new[:-1]:
                old[-1] += ' '+new[-1]
            else:
                w.writerow(old)
                old = new
        w.writerow(old)
```

To check what I've proposed you can use these two snippets (note that these records are shorter than yours, but it's an example and it doesn't matter because we use only `-1` to index our records).

The 1st one has a "regular" last record

```
open('a0.csv', 'w').write('1,1,2\n1,1,3\n1,2,0\n1,3,1\n1,3,2\n3,3,0\n')
join('a0.csv', 'a1.csv')
```

while the 2nd has a last record that must be joined to the previous one.

```
open('b0.csv', 'w').write('1,1,2\n1,1,3\n1,2,0\n1,3,1\n1,3,2\n')
join('b0.csv', 'b1.csv')
```

If you run the snippets, as I have done before posting, in the environment where you have defined `join` you should get what you want.